# Hyperledger participation without hosting a peer node

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are looking to implement a hyperledger-fabric solution and I'm stumped by this fundamental question. How is a hyperledger solution architected if not all participants are able/willing to host a peer node?

Our users are divided into 2 groups - payers and providers. Most of our providers are willing and have the IT infrastructure required to host a peer node. Many of our payers are/do not.

From the perspective of a payer participant how can I trust the system if I'm not a peer and don't have my own copy of the ledger? What options might we have in setting up a hyperledger environment that allows them to participate?

Apologies if I have missed the point or some documentation that describes this scenario but links to it would be most welcome.

Comment: I assume payers are primarily submitting transactions?

Comment: @GariSingh Primarily yes, but both sides will be interested in seeing the current state of a transaction and might need to make updates to it until it is ultimately closed or resolved. I should note that I've simplified the makeup of our users. There are at least 2 more distinct groups unaffiliated with either payers or providers. Again some can host, others can't. Does hyperledger support the notion of not hosting a node but trusting another participant who does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest "trust assumption" is for groups which don't run peers to trust a specific member who is running a peer.  For submitting transactions, it really does not matter if you run a node or not ... you would likely care about the endorsement policy in effect to make sure that there is not one all powerful member with a peer, but other than that you submit to multiple peers for endorsement anyway.  For querying data, as mentioned you might have affinity / trust for one particular member, you might select a random or majority set of peers and do a "strong read".  A query is still an invoke so you can actually query multiple peers in the same call.